# A notation $H$ on top of matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Could anyone tell me what the $H$ notation generally used on the top of some matrices is meant to be in this paper by [Schmidt](https://hal-polytechnique.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01020654/document)? The first usage is in equation 2.9 on page 9. Does it mean to be Hermitian?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose). Also denoted $A^*$ or $A^\dagger$. But I prefer to at least change the font somehow like $A^{\rm H}$ or $A^{\sf H}$ so it doesn't get confused with exponentiation.

Comment: Generally, Physics people use $A^{\dagger}$, I will stick to $A^{\star}$. Thank you.